# Dividir un arreglo en divisiones exactas

Tags: javascript

Tengo un arreglo de 10 elementos y quiero dividirlos de 2 en 2 elementos.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
let res = [];
let parcial = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  parcial.push(array[i]);

  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    res.push(parcial);
    parcial = [];
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

El resultado esperado es: `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,0]]`, pero lo que obtengo es

```
[
  [1],
  [2, 3],
  [4, 5],
  [6, 7],
  [8, 9]
]
```

como lo soluciono?

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta? segun tu ejemplo, eso esta andando

Comment: @ManucoBianco necesito este resultado El resultado esperado es: [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,0]], edite mi pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es el uso del índice: la primera posición es 0, la segunda 1, con lo que la condición para insertar la pareja debería ser `i % 2 === 1` (impar):

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
let res = [];
let parcial = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  parcial.push(array[i]);

  if (i % 2 === 1) {
    res.push(parcial);
    parcial = [];
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

Otra solución sería usar [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice):

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

function trocear(array,tamTrozo) {
  let result=[];

  for (let i=0; i < array.length; i+=tamTrozo) {
    result.push(array.slice(i,i+tamTrozo));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(trocear(array,2));
console.log(trocear(array,3));
console.log(trocear(array,5));
```